# Solving $1 - 3xy + x^3 + y^3 = 0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, real-numbers

I am trying to solve the equation
$$
1 - 3xy + x^3 + y^3 = 0
$$
in the real numbers. I can see several (infinitely many) solutions:

1. $x=y = 1$
2. $x+ y = -1$

I am trying to show that these are all of them.

For example, if $x = y$, then $x^2(-3+2x) = -1$ forcing $x = y = 1$

I can't seem to make much progress with the case where $x\neq y$ and showing that $x + y = 1$ in that case. (I am pretty sure that this must be true.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, consider the transformation

$$x=u+v$$

$$y=u-v.$$

Then $1-3x_0y_0+x_0^3+y_0^3=0$ if and only if $(1 + 2 u_0) ((-1+ u_0)^2 + 3 v_0^2)=0$ where

$$u_0=\frac{x_0+y_0}{2}$$

$$v_0=\frac{x_0-y_0}{2}.$$

Now, one possible solution is

$$1+2u=0\Rightarrow \frac{x+y}{2}=u=\frac{-1}{2}\Rightarrow x+y=-1$$

which is what you found. In fact, there is only one other solution as

$$(-1 + u)^2 + 3 v^2\geq 0$$

with equality happening at $(u,v)=(1,0)$. Thus, the only other zero is

$$(u,v)=(1,0)\Rightarrow (x,y)=(1,1)$$

which is what you also found. We conclude the only zeros are at

$$x=y=1$$

$$x+y=-1.$$

Answer (score 2):

For the case $x,y\ge 0$ by AM-GM

$$x^3+y^3+1\ge3\sqrt[3]{x^3y^3}=3xy$$

with equality if and only if $x=y=1$.

Answer (score 1):

If you substitute $y$ with $-x-1$ you get the identity
$$x^3+(-x-1)^3-3x(-x-1)+1=0$$

This means that the polynomial $x^3+y^3-3xy+1$ is divisible by $x+y+1$. Performing long division you get the following factorization:
$$x^3+y^3-3xy+1= (x+y+1)(x^2-xy+y^2-x-y+1)$$
so the problem becomes proving that $(x;y)=(1;1)$ is the only zero for
$$x^2-xy+y^2-x-y+1=0$$
Call $X=x-1$ and $Y=y-1$. We want to prove that $X=Y=0$. Substituting $x=X+1$ and $y=Y+1$, we get the equation
$$X^2-XY+Y^2=0$$
whose unique solution is $X=Y=0$ (hope you can find the reason of this by yourself). This concludes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Worth memorizing:
$$ x^3 + y^3 + z^3 - 3xyz = (x+y+z) \left(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - yz - zx - xy  \right)  $$
Another step is possible, in that
$$ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - yz - zx - xy = \frac{1}{2} \; \left((x-y)^2 + ( y-z)^2 + ( z-x)^2 \right)  $$

The cubic is zero, for real numbers $x,y,z,$  when either
$x+y+z = 0$  or $x=y=z.$ In your case, take $z=1$

More solutions are possible over the complexes, in that the quadratic further factors as
$$ (x+\omega y + \omega^2 z)(x + \omega^2 y + \omega z) $$
where $\omega$ is a primitive cube root of unity.

Answer (score 0):

You will get infinite solution when $x$ and $y$ are not equal as the relation $x+y=-1$ gives different values of $x$, when you are changing $y$ .Check this https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-3xy%2Bx%5E3%2By%5E3%3D0

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to prove.

Comment: You may check the link @JohnDoe, it is shown by factorising the equation

Answer (score 0):

$$x=u+v$$

$$x^3=u^3+v^3+3uv(x)\iff x^3-3uv(x)-(u^3+v^3)=0$$

Comparing with $$x^3-3xy+y^3+1=0$$

$$uv=y$$

and $$ u^3+v^3=-(y^3+1)\iff u^3+\dfrac{y^3}{u^3}+y^3+1=0$$

$$0=u^6+(y^3+1)u^3+y^3=(u^3+1)(u^3+y^3)$$

If $u^3+1=0,u=-1,\implies v=-y$

$$\implies x=u+v=-1-y\iff x+y=-1$$

$$x^3+y^3-3xy+1=(x+y)^3-3xy(x+y+1)+1=0$$